# Lib.Web.Mvc, JqGridColumnModel class's CellAttributes not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, lib.web.mvc

I am using Lib.Web.Mvc (version 6.1.0) to generate jqgrid in client.

Most attribute of JqGridColumnModel work fine but **CellAttributes** has not any effection here.

This is my Code:

---

```
configuration.Settings.ColumnsModels.AddRange(new JqGridColumnModel[]
{
new JqGridColumnModel("ProductID") { Index = "ProductID" },
new JqGridColumnModel("ProductName") {  Index = "ProductName" },
new JqGridColumnModel("SupplierID") {  Index = "SupplierID" },
new JqGridColumnModel("CategoryID") {  Index = "CategoryID" },
new JqGridColumnModel("QuantityPerUnit") {  Index = "QuantityPerUnit"},
```

new JqGridColumnModel("UnitPrice") {  Index = "UnitPrice", *CellAttributes**="value=1"}
});

---

I don't know if CellAttributes still not work in lastes version 6.1.0? Or I don't know how to use it.

Please give me idea to add more attributes to cell from server side (controller).

Answer (score 0):

The `JqGridColumnModel.CellAttributes` is a proxy to `cellattr` property of `colModel`. This property takes a JavaScript function which should return string with attributes. Below you can find corresponding part from [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options):

> This function add attributes to the cell during the creation of the data - i.e dynamically. By example all valid attributes for the table cell can be used or a style attribute with different properties. The function should return string. ...

And from [Lib.Web.Mvc documentation](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Lib.Web.Mvc/Lib.Web.Mvc/JqGridColumnModel/P/CellAttributes):

> Gets or sets the function which can add attributes to the cell during the creation of the data (dynamically).

So in your case the code should look like this:

```
configuration.Settings.ColumnsModels.AddRange(new JqGridColumnModel[]
{
    new JqGridColumnModel("ProductID") { Index = "ProductID" },
    new JqGridColumnModel("ProductName") {  Index = "ProductName" },
    new JqGridColumnModel("SupplierID") {  Index = "SupplierID" },
    new JqGridColumnModel("CategoryID") {  Index = "CategoryID" },
    new JqGridColumnModel("QuantityPerUnit") {  Index = "QuantityPerUnit" },
    new JqGridColumnModel("UnitPrice") { Index = "UnitPrice", CellAttributes = "function() { return 'value=1'; }" }
});
```

**UPDATE**

There is one special case, the configuration import and export functionality. In this case all the settings for JavaScript functions, events and callbacks are ignored as those can't be serialized to JSON (this is by design).

Comment: Hello, I have just tried that way. But result is not as expectation.

Comment: @QuangMy What was the expected result? Attribute 'value' is not valid attribute for TD element and it has no visual effect, so the only possible result can be seen in generated HTML of grid - have you inspected it?

Comment: I have tried that way. But result is not as expectation. cellattr cannot be return via colmodels. Please see my image which debug by firebug: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TfAqg.png

Comment: @QuangMy Well I guess you didn't read my update. All the properties which sets some king of JavaScript function, callback or event can't be used in import/export configuration scenario. This limit is not introduced on Lib.Web.Mvc level but on jqGrid level as those can't be serialized into JSON. In the configuration import/export scenario all the JavaScript functions, callback and events should be set client side after the import is finished.